# Are good leaving groups good in both directions?

Tags: kinetics, enzyme-kinetics

In biology, phosphate groups are often used, good leaving groups.

If I had an opposite case, where a phosphate group remains bound to an enzyme while the main substrate is removed (e.g. E-P04-S => E-PO4 + S) is the substrate considered a good leaving group?

Put another way, **does the fact that Phosphate is a good leaving group affect the ease at which S is removed?**

Comment: Can you specify whether the whole PO4 is coming off the substrate or if just PO3 is removed? In the former case, something needs to add to the substrate to replace the PO4 or there needs to be deprotonation/elimination

Comment: @Andrew Sorry, I may have been too vague in my example. To clarify, I am thinking of a pTyr phosphatase in this example. This enzyme has an intermediate where after the phosphate is removed from the tyrosine, it is covalently bound to a Cys in the enzyme active site. I am wondering if the elimination of Tyr from the Tyr-PO4-Enz complex is energetically favorable as normal PO4 hydrolysis. As you're still breaking the S-OPO3 bond. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Based on your description, you are breaking the SO-PO3 bond not (as you wrote) the S-OPO3 bond, right? That is what happens in normal hydrolysis of a phosphate group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you are correct that phosphate is a good leaving group, it does not play that role in the reaction you described.

[image]
Source: https://doi.org/10.1074/jbc.273.17.10454

The reaction catalyzed by protein tyrosine phosphatase is an example of a "phosphoryl transfer" reaction, that is, the transfer of $\ce{PO3^-}$ from one compound to another. From a chemistry point of view, this is a nucleophilic substitution at the electrophilic phosphorus atom.

In the uncatalyzed reaction, water is the nucleophile and tyrosinate (or tyrosine if the O has been protonated) is the leaving group. In the enzyme active site, water is replaced by cysteine as the nucleophile as you described.

Examples of reactions in which phosphate is truly a leaving group are glycosyl transferases that use glucose 1-phosphate as a substrate and the hydrolysis of pyrophosphate, in which one phosphorus atom is the electrophilic site and the other is part of the phosphate leaving group.

With respect to your main question, since the leaving group in both the catalyzed and uncatalyzed reaction is tyrosinate or tyrosine, a key question is the protonation state of the tyrosine oxygen. Tyrosine (protonated) is a much better leaving group than tyrosinate (unprotonated).

On the other side, a sulfide ($\ce{-S^-}$) group is a much better nucleophile than a sulfhydryl ($\ce{-SH}$) or water, but not as good as hydroxide, so that will also make a difference.

Lastly, the protonation state of the oxygens on the phosphoryl group will have an effect on how electrophilic it is, an effect which is independent of the identity of the nucleophile.

All of that is to say that you need to be very specific about what two reactions exactly you are comparing.